How to add values from a column if two conditions are true?
For example, this table:



Column A
Column B
Column C




1/1/2000
qwe
2


2/1/2000
asd
3


3/1/2000
zxc
4



I want to add up the values of column C if the day from the date on column A is minor or equal to 2 and the text on column B is "qwe".
But it's not working the way I'm doing it. I tried it like this
=SUM.IF(AND(DAY(A1:A3)<=2,B1:B3="qwe"),C1:C3)

That should return the result of 5, but it returns 0 as result...
Thanks in advance.

Because SUMIFS() criterial range must be pure cell range, not calculated virtual range/column. Try SUMPRODUCT() instead.
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C4)*(DAY(A2:A4)<=2)*(B2:B4="qwe"))

Or FILTER() function.
=FILTER(C2:C4,(DAY(A2:A4)<=2)*(B2:B4="qwe"),0)



Sorry, I had a mistake on the expected result. What I'm trying to do is add the cells on column C if the day on column A is minor or equal to 2. The expected result in the example should be 5.

@JuanZepeda The use =SUMPRODUCT((C2:C4)*(DAY(A2:A4)<=2)) or =SUM(FILTER(C2:C4,DAY(A2:A4)<=2,0)).
